# Python- pyramid doesn't run local host

Tags: pyramid

I am trying to install and run python pyramid.

I installed `anaconda`, created a virtual environment and used `pip install "pyramid==1.7.3"` to install pyramid.

Then executed

```
   `from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    from pyramid.config import Configurator
    from pyramid.response import Response


    def hello_world(request):
        return Response('Hello %(name)s!' % request.matchdict)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        config = Configurator()
        config.add_route('hello', '/hello/{name}')
        config.add_view(hello_world, route_name='hello')
        app = config.make_wsgi_app()
        server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
        server.serve_forever()`
```

this `helloworld.py`. This doesn't start the server and when I open the `localhost:8080` in the browser, it gave me a `404 Not Found The resource could not be found.` Error.

here is the [Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot98y.png)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your server did start and is running.  Try using "localhost:8080/hello/john"

Comment: Yea it's serving at " http://localhost:8080/hello/world"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For newbies to web application development in Python, I recommend working through the [Quick Tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/index.html).  Do not skip over any steps, including Requirements.  It provides a good overview of creating web applications in Python and its ecosystem, with references for further in-depth reading.

Anaconda is targeted toward the data science audience.  In our documentation, we don't provide specific instructions for how to work within Anaconda, so you would have to learn that part on your own.

Answer (score 1):

It was serving at  ' http://localhost:8080/hello/world ' not in the 'localhost:8080'